# How can I read in and bind together several data frames without using a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

`for()` loops in `R` always seem to be my go-to for reading in multiple things but there must be a better way of doing what I want to do.

Let's say I have several data sets that all come from an automated data-pull system:

```
#Fake data set up
library(lubridate)

dir_path <- tempdir()
file_1 <- paste0(Sys.Date() - days(2), ".rds")
file_2 <-paste0(Sys.Date() - days(1), ".rds")
file_3 <- paste0(Sys.Date(), ".rds")

data.frame(thing = rnorm(100)) %>%
    saveRDS(file.path(dir_path, file_1))

data.frame(thing = rnorm(100)) %>%
    saveRDS(file.path(dir_path, file_2))

data.frame(thing = rnorm(100)) %>%
    saveRDS(file.path(dir_path, file_3))
```

I want to read each of these into my R session, do a small bit of processing, to each, then stick them all into the same dataframe:

```
read_in_data <- function(file_name, dir){

    d <- substr(file_name, 1, 10)
    thing <- 
        readRDS(file.path(dir, file_name)) %>%
        mutate(date = d)
}

files <- list.files(temp_dir(), pattern = "^2017-1")

this_thing <- NULL

for(i in 1:length(files)){
    this_thing <- 
        this_thing %>%
        bind_rows(read_in_data(files[i], dir_path))
}
```

This is great and does exactly what I want, but I have the sneaking suspicion that, as the number of files I want to read in and bind together grows, the `for()` loop will end up being very slow.

I could do something like

```
this_thing <- 
    read_in_data(files[1], dir_path) %>%
    bind_rows(read_in_data(files[2], dir_path)) %>%
    bind_rows(read_in_data(files[3], dir_path))
```

but this is gross and will be impossible to maintain, especially as the number of files I want to read in grows.

How can I get rid of this `for` loop? I know that growing things in a `for()` loop is a bad idea but I don't know how else to do this kind of operation. What am I missing? Probably something pretty simple.

Comment: `bind_rows(lapply(files, read_in_data, dir_path))`

Comment: The most efficient way is to put all your df in a list. Then do all processing with `lapply`. Finally you can merge the list of dfs in one single df. There are many examples of this in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

files %>%
    map(safely(read_in_data, quiet = FALSE)) %>%
    transpose() %>%
    simplify_all() %>%
    .result() %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    saveRDS(file.path("path to .rds file"))
```